# Rails projects and Rails version changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I started to learn/work with RoR starting with version 3.0.0. I work on multiple/different projects at once and some of them are not finished yet. The current version of RoR is 3.0.7.
I am curious what other developers do.

Do you update your current projects to the last version of RoR when it changes, or you just stick to the version the project was created on and using the new RoR version just for new projects?

I am asking this because I can't decide (like "to be, or not to be") should I stick to one version or should I keep updating the current projects for the new RoR release versions.

PS: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to stay up to date with the latests 'small' releases. For example moving from Rails 3.0.5 to 3.0.7 probably isn't going to be a big deal. (However, I'd still checkout http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/ for details). But it does mean that you'll get all the security and performance updates.

But moving from 2.3 - 3.0 will require work! Which is why it always makes it easier to stay pretty up to date. As soon as you start falling behind it only makes it more difficult to upgrade in the future.

Further, as long as you've got decent test coverage you can just update the version, run your tests and check if everything works.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should update if possible, just think of security fixes. Checkout your project from Git, update and see, if your test suite still passes. Normally, moving up minor releases does not break anything.